# How to change styles of menu in a Nokia Qt application

Tags: qt, nokia

I want to create menu in Nokia Qt, and I am very new to Qt,. I have added screen shot. And I want to create menu like shown in that screen shot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is just a styled application. Qt supports CSS for styling controls, so just look it up in the documentation (it's QStyle or something like that.)